# How to hash JSX class names and css class names in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I need my react project build version to have hashed class names in in html and css. For example if I have:

```
<div className="test"></div>
```

I need to be build like this:

```
<div class="*hashcode*"></div>
```

can this be achieved in React?

Answer (score 1):

You need [CSS modules](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/).

Create a file named `[componentName].module.css` with your component. Let us say it looks like:

```
.divClass {
background-color : red;
}
```

Import it like a JS object:

```
import styles from './random.module.css`;
```

And use it here:

```
<div className={styles.divClass}></div>
```

[Link to docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `webpack` to build the scaffold from scratch, please continue to read(I assume you had set other configurations done).

Here are the steps

**1 set the webpack config file**

```
module.exports = {
...
module: {
      rules: [
         {
          test: /\.(scss)$/i,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            "style-loader",
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                  modules: {
                    exportLocalsConvention: "camelCaseOnly",
                    localIdentName: "[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]",
                  },
              },
            },
            "sass-loader",
          ],
        },
...
}
```

**2 create a scss file**

```
// App.scss

.hello {
    color: red;
}
```

**3 Import the scss file and use it.**

```
// App.jsx
import Style from './App.scss';

const App = () => {
    return <div className={Style.hello}>Hello World!</div>
}
```

Then you should figure it out.

Since you want to add hash to className, you must handle the CSS flow.
It would help if you had the tool `css-loader`. The option `localIdentName` in `modules` allows to configure the generated local ident name.

For more info check [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#modules)